# How to know if PropertyInfo is MEF import

Tags: c#, reflection, mef, propertyinfo

Suppose I have a class as follows where `MyProperty` is composed in by MEF:

```
class Foo
{
    [Import]
    public Bar MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

While using reflection to inspect this assembly, is it possible to determine whether the property was imported by MEF? I noticed an `Attributes` property in the `PropertyInfo` class but it was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `GetCustomAttributes()` method instead.